# Pass command-line arguments to Groovy script

Tags: groovy

I have a simple Groovy script like this:

```
class Main {
    static void main(String... args) {
        args.each {
            println ${it}
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out how to pass command line arguments to it. I'm on Windows and run the script as:

> Groovy myscript.groovy "arg1" "arg2"

And it results in error:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Main$_main_closure1.$() is applicable for argument types: (Main$_main_closure1$_closure2) values: [Main$_main_closure1$_closure2@68b32e3e]
>   Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object), any(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Main$_main_closure1.$() is applicable for argument types: (Main$_main_closure1$_closure2) values: [Main$_main_closure1$_closure2@68b32e3e]
>   Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), is(java.lang.Object), any(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
>           at Main$_main_closure1.doCall(hash_text.groovy:10)
>           at Main.main(hash_text.groovy:9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have just a syntax error. instead of

```
println ${it}
```

use

```
println it
```

or

```
println "${it}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you had an explicit reason to do so, but you don't need an explicit class in groovy scripts. Also, there is an implicit `args` collection automatically injected into your script.

In other words, pasting the following contents into a `test.groovy`

```
println "ARGS:  $args"
println "CLASS: ${args.class}"
```

gives the following execution result:

```
~> groovy test.groovy foo bar
ARGS:  [foo, bar]
CLASS: class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

where the class printout means that the implicit `args` variable is of type String array.